# indexOf + substring in Java

Tags: java

I am stuck concerning an exercise, the goal is to enter a name  and recuperate  the value from name. example (`vanitoglo`)

Then I must to slice the 3 first characters from letters with the method `substring()` and store on a variable news - for the example we have the word `<van>`

I now compare the value  from this variable which is `<van>` with the word `<van>` if the word begins with `<van>`

I must to have a message that "the word entered begins with `<van>`"

Or else "the word does not start with `<van>` "

My problem is I don't know how to do to search on all characters with the indexOf()

for example if the `<van>` is at the end or in the middle I must to have a message ("The word `<van>` is included all over")

I already a error message here:

```
word_search = name_enter.indexOf("van");
```

Here is my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String name_enter  = ""; //  enter the name
String word_sub    = ""; //  word slice
String word_search = ""; //  word search all over

System.out.print("Enter your name : ");

name_enter = input.next();
word_sub = name_enter.substring(0,3);
word_search = name_enter.indexOf("van");

if (word_sub.equals("van")) {
    System.out.print("The word begins with <van> ");
} else {
    if (word_search > 0) {
        System.out.print("the word <van> is included all over");
    } else {
        System.out.print("the word does not start with <van> ");
    }
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` returns an `int` , not a `String` .

Comment: "I already a error message here:" - it would help if you'd include the error message. In the current case it becomes quite obvious if we read the code but please don't make us guess, just tell us the error you get.

Comment: You should understand and fix error message instead of asking someone else. You'll spend hours and days to programm a few line if you wait for somone each time you have an error ;)

Comment: @Thomas: sorry => Incompatible types. Required: java.lang.String Found: int

Comment: @Arnaud, so not possible with indexOf?

Comment: You can use `indexOf()` and check whether it returns 0 (which means the substring has been found right at the first character) but if you're only after that then you could use `startsWith()` just as well. - In fact you've already written `word_search > 0` so all you'd need to do is change the type of `word_search` (I'll ignore style issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner();

String nameEntry = null;   //  enter the name
int vanIndex = 0;     //  index of van
boolean wordPresent = false;  //  word search all over

System.out.print("Enter your name :");
nameEntry = input.next();

vanIndex = nameEntry.indexOf("van");

if(vanIndex > 0){
    wordPresent = true;
}

if(wordPresent){
//do whatever
}
```

Comment: I don't suggest you use _ as variable name separators. Research camelCase also.

Comment: @ Max Shannon: ok mercy for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains instead of indexof for your purpose and you have to make "word_search" parameter boolean:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String name_enter = "";   //  enter the name
String word_sub = "";     //  word slice
boolean word_search = false;  //  word search all over


System.out.print("Enter your name : ");
name_enter = input.next();

word_sub = name_enter.substring(0,3);

word_search = name_enter.contains("van");

if(word_sub.equals("van")){
    System.out.print("The word begins with <van> ");
}

else{
    if(word_search == true){
        System.out.print("the word <van> is included all over");

    }

    else{
        System.out.print("the word does not start with <van> ");
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you a lot, is it possible to do with IndexOf? please